# ice:commandButton works after second click

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

i am using jsf 2.0 and icefaces 3.0. i have migrated my application from icefaces 1.8 to 3.0 but 
i am facing one issue for ice:commandbutton on every jsf page. it needs second click everytime then its sending the response to the broswer, i debugeed the issue by using IE developer tools (F12 in IE) by using network tab. so when i am hitting first time i am getting following repsonse :

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><changes><update id="javax.faces.ViewState"><![CDATA[8640112048343005235:64165239481062360]]></update><extension aceCallbackParam="validationFailed">{"validationFailed":false}</extension></changes></partial-response>
```

and on second click it working.

following is my button code.

```
<ice:commandButton value="#{msgs['submit.label']}"
                                            id="submitCmd2" type="submit"
                                            actionListener="#{applicationController.submit}"
                                            rendered="true" styleClass="buttonpurple" onclick="showLoader();"
                                            style="width: 125px; " align="center" />
```

but i am not able to understand what is the cause and what solution i need to use to solve this problem. also i have gone through balusC links [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the code of your button actually?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie i have added button code please look into this

Comment: @BalusC please look into this..

Comment: I think i got the problem is about life cycle issue.. on jsf page i have valuechangelisteners and each valuechangelistener has line FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();  i commented that line and then its working but i am not able to find why they are using renderResponse at the end of valueChangeListener.. and commenting this line is there any side effectes...

Comment: `@nickname` comment-replies works only if the person in question has commented on the post before.

Comment: @BalusC Sorry for that could you please help me with this..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `actionListener` try `action` in ice:commandbutton. There are some [differences-between-action-and-actionlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener).

```
<ice:commandButton value="#{msgs['submit.label']}"
                                        id="submitCmd2" type="submit"
                                        action="#{applicationController.submit}"
                                        rendered="true" styleClass="buttonpurple" onclick="showLoader();"
                                        style="width: 125px; " align="center" />
```

Also type='submit' is not required, by default it is submit.

Comment: @vels4j Thanks and i agree with you but i dont think it will solve the problem please look into the xml response which i mentioned in the problem..

Comment: What is ShowLoader in onClick ?. Also give a try with partialSubmit="true"

Comment: its just for showing one loading image and tried with partialSubmit="true" as well...

Comment: for that you can use ice:outputConnectionStatus http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf;jsessionid=D91E1EEDF6C7564BD02C8A822271C0F9?grp=compatMenu&exp=connectionStatus

Answer (score 0):

You can try the workaround described [here](http://jira.icesoft.org/browse/ICE-5691)

If that doesn't work, you can try ajax with jsf commandbutton, in it's own best way.

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msgs['submit.label']}"
                                    id="submitCmd2" 
                                    actionListener="#{applicationController.submit}"
                                    styleClass="buttonpurple" onclick="showLoader();"
                                    style="width: 125px; " align="center">
  <f:ajax execute="id1 id2 id3...." render="@form"/>
</h:commandButton>
```